# How to include a Bootstrap glyphicon in an email with Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have an app that sends out a notification email. I would like to include a Bootstrap glyphicon in the email, but what I'm doing just results in a blank space where the link should be (I'm using the glyphicon for a link button).

Here is the code being used in my email template:

```
<a href="{{ action('QualityControlCorrectionController@create', [$workorder->id, $finding->finding_number]) }}" style="margin-left: 2px; color: #EC9720;" title="Submit a Correction"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></a>
```

I have also included the CDN for the Bootstrap library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

That doesn't seem like I'm giving you much in the way of code, but aside from the standard `Mail::send()` function and html part of my email template, there's nothing else to it.

Comment: The answer is quite simple: you need to use YES/NO. You'll need to do a request external sources to load those icons, and many people blocks them, so by using icons, you'd be effectively blocking yourself and sending incomplete emails. That's why you need to use inline CSS styles in emails, because even loading your CSS stylesheet will be blocked.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @STA. I hadn't considered that people could/would block an external library. I'm not sure what you mean by: `"you need to use YES/NO"`?